# Server cas with ldap backend and building with maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, ldap, cas

I have problems to connect my server cas-server-4.1.7 with my ldap base,
please I need solution.

Thanks.

Error with maven
[image: error with maven]

My file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml
[image: My file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

    <!--
       | The authentication manager defines security policy for authentication by specifying at a minimum
       | the authentication handlers that will be used to authenticate credential. While the AuthenticationManager
       | interface supports plugging in another implementation, the default PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager should
       | be sufficient in most cases.
<bean id="contextSource " class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler" p:filter="mail=%u" p:searchBase="ou=People,dc=isetb,dc=tn" p:contextSource-ref="contextSource"/>
<property name="pooled" value="false"/>
<property name="url" value="ldap://192.168.251.37"/>
<property name="userDn" value="cn=Manager,dc=isetb,dc=tn"/>
<property name="password" value="haykel1924"/>
<property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
<map>
<entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="3000"/>
<entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout" value="3000"/>
<entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
</map>
</property>
<bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Kindly, it will better to include the code for the error and xml file instead using screenshots. Please update your question with that codes. Also try to ask a question with `?` at the end…